# assigning a oracle PLSQL variable with URL

Tags: oracle, variables, url, plsql, escaping

I have a task in which i need to create a rest API call within a stored procedure in Oracle.

I have looked at the following documentation as an example.

https://technology.amis.nl/2015/05/11/invoke-a-rest-service-from-plsql-make-an-http-post-request-using-utl_http-in-oracle-database-11g-xe/

in my PLSQL i am trying to set my url variable to the following string:

```
https://localhost/access_token?client_id=1234&client_secret=1234&grant_type=client_credentials
```

using the following

```
v_url := 'https://localhost/access_token?client_id=1234'||chr(38) ||'client_secret=1234'||chr(38) ||'grant_type=client_credentials';
```

However the variable is not being set as it is coming back null.  The variable can be set up to the point before the '&'

```
create or replace procedure mule_test( p_clientid in varchar2, 
p_clientsecret in varchar2) 

AS

  req utl_http.req;
  res utl_http.resp;
  v_url VARCHAR2(255);  v_name VARCHAR2(255);
  v_buffer varchar2(4000); 
  v_content varchar2(4000);


 begin

    v_url := 'https://localhost/access_token?client_id=1234'||chr(38) 
    ||'client_secret=1234'||chr(38) ||'grant_type=client_credentials';
```

Answer (score 1):

Works OK for me:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    v_url varchar2(200);
  3  begin
  4    v_url := 'https://localhost/access_token?client_id=1234'||chr(38) ||'client_secret=1234'||chr(38) ||'grant_type=client_credentials';
  5    dbms_output.put_line(v_url);
  6  end;
  7  /
https://localhost/access_token?client_id=1234&client_secret=1234&grant_type=client_credentials

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: i also did a dbms output and it did display there, but I dont know why I can't see the vairable being set upon mousing over while in debug mode.

Comment: Which tool do you use? (i.e. what "mousing over" and "debug mode" represent)

Comment: Im using toad for oracle.. mousing over works if I dont use the &.  So my assumption was the string variable was not being set when it was trying to make the post request       req := utl_http.begin_request(v_url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');